# Java HashMap.Entry class not found

Tags: java, hashmap, classnotfoundexception

I am dealing with problem. The code throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap.Entry"

```
Class.forName("java.util.HashMap.Entry");
```

Anybody knows how can I create class to store HashMap.Entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Class.forName("java.util.HashMap$Entry");
```

(note the dollar sign.)

This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap.Entry` isn't public, although it does exist. You should be able to fetch it (as `java.util.HashMap$Entry`) but as it's not a public type you probably shouldn't be using it.

`Map.Entry` is public, but it doesn't have that name - it's `java.util.Map$Entry` due to being a nested class.

If you're hard-coding this, why not just use a class literal?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Class<?> clazz = Map.Entry.class;
        System.out.println(clazz.getName()); // java.util.Map$Entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HashMap.Entry doesn't seem to be an inner class of Java 8 anymore